# How to call specific data in json object

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Ok I am making an api call to google places API and getting back a JSON object.  I have been able to do work with this object with Ajax but now I have to integrate my code into a Wordpress instance and I am making the API call inside functions.php because I want to use the get_theme_mod(); method.

Since I am fairly new to php I don't know how to output specific data from this object.

My object is below, I am trying to access the reviews returned by this object (all 5).  I know I can do this with Ajax fairly easily but I am really struggling with the syntax in PHP.

This is my PHP API call

```
function do_api_call(){
$url = $my_url;
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$rev = json_encode($data);
echo $rev;

}



{"html_attributions":[],"result":{"address_components":[{"long_name":"76","short_name":"76","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"North Main Street","short_name":"N Main St","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Concord","short_name":"Concord","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Merrimack County","short_name":"Merrimack County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"New Hampshire","short_name":"NH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"03301","short_name":"03301","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"4915","short_name":"4915","types":["postal_code_suffix"]}],"adr_address":"<span class=\"street-address\">76 N Main St</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Concord</span>, <span class=\"region\">NH</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">03301-4915</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>","formatted_address":"76 N Main St, Concord, NH 03301, USA","formatted_phone_number":"(603) 856-7181","geometry":{"location":{"lat":43.20638719999999,"lng":-71.53594079999999},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":43.20770828029149,"lng":-71.53477561970848},"southwest":{"lat":43.2050103197085,"lng":-71.5374735802915}}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png","id":"9496ddb6eb5f976d65d829a5bc2a11c16235f24c","international_phone_number":"+1 603-856-7181","name":"The Crazy Goat","opening_hours":{"open_now":true,"periods":[{"close":{"day":0,"time":"1800"},"open":{"day":0,"time":"1200"}},{"close":{"day":2,"time":"2200"},"open":{"day":2,"time":"1200"}},{"close":{"day":3,"time":"2200"},"open":{"day":3,"time":"1200"}},{"close":{"day":4,"time":"2200"},"open":{"day":4,"time":"1200"}},{"close":{"day":5,"time":"2200"},"open":{"day":5,"time":"1200"}},{"close":{"day":6,"time":"2200"},"open":{"day":6,"time":"1200"}}],"weekday_text":["Monday: Closed","Tuesday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM","Wednesday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM","Thursday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM","Friday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM","Saturday: 12:00 – 10:00 PM","Sunday: 12:00 – 6:00 PM"]},"photos":[{"height":1536,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109874917867182741893/photos\">The Crazy Goat</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAuVKW68MbnuWHZyE8nw6AfMeYfqR8hoZBNmlFFReExDzbgqrkY2NtZro_f8cBWLRzVTajatvGjpv9Mffqv_zeCFuGJIz0jBreCN-0d8YQkc11gzjwZT_-TVS-dwvvx0efEhD_NXSEyy9Q7VZJd2tIFK_iGhT-pd1t-6YpKzhr8nVvaGlfFv36gw","width":2048},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115623591626747192241/photos\">a beauregard</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAA8jPB2uPOxWd_-1inL9GMO7tWdIfhvaVCYFODb2yessHQ_Jy7Wyo99z9Qrlohho0tdFlz4GyuGgtO1CEirdeLYJJb25QbX4ZdBClQwDjYBDUC0spd_tPFLAnsFCLk664ZEhBGqm26u-aeqnDBQzWKPTc2GhR2OUmpnyErQr3rsbmOC92nva595A","width":4032},{"height":2988,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111065387557395503043/photos\">Vicky and Snickers Anderson</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRZAAAAk-Z3Ml_aMD8_xwpZBT85JDfd9dtrq_LponeZICHGhbRp1KozF4H8Ig36ikIYcbJyH0DWf-4_ylRWviWYDBkuJWcKyvHRSzjquxuE_MNN5FjjkWX3aPBcNWxTnh9RQ8OcEhAE9Y91__B86071fFBuZFDAGhSF5XxgaAxsUl8Im4_lgVCMIgGPNA","width":5312},{"height":4032,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115623591626747192241/photos\">a beauregard</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAgaVjlQzuv7F-88pv8GPd-IkGzo9oH1gQoKc_ZmVmQjVqWeeljkVLSsti3oLzkau3IXW3JOJ7KyOvlsOUTGNOJnBA31OIttfCbmCFPSCiyywmu7yUHnf_w0CKLw5hT_RWEhCpSZtnAKj3umsNcJUtI7K3GhR4g14ff5ekvKuB_rW0YlL_FWotxg","width":3024},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115623591626747192241/photos\">a beauregard</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAA3so1UtaPCAqJlbpxhyfbBefycY4FspxrNPDBH-xeBoTMTgkTCb3uT9p8l3Umgu2VpCatqTu3fDFgbj5VmjNGvk7ngtYYhD2UCMXoCxuxHjL9kzvoaDdL8SoyJUFWBnlZEhCeTxLqrBsM8R6IPd8iK_h2GhTmgvfEor4xDZNha0teaiw3KyHhrQ","width":4032},{"height":4032,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111580933990207571063/photos\">Michael Brady</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAlxoITLsevfPLrsV5rCHt1IuJBs-sKE6tTuQmmKg6xbAi2puyrhlG3aEY9GoFUCRpApEL30TssUQPN31U6kkCdIDofmJktXYvpvJ9nb2EItJDyVE32s7XE15XJEx3mvPKEhA19O6fhPnSKbSD2bE-lTqPGhRjw-0d1TspjpQC3yhez71pWyJKOA","width":3024},{"height":2592,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110913511470452374693/photos\">Maxwell Murdoch Snelling</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAApttZtrF9LRbcVHeCokgPipfdh-Gs-v6G9ze8vAXh2YPP8PEx3cWy7AEgY72_79VFPAMWTkKgbrOceNiqn7t6R0USgUvD9hnPq_WLc9jPt-Fbwt0HwoO2QZtb0l7Xry_IEhD9SRgHx9fiVLGWyxfIs67LGhSprzTG6Srq3f4HkpBZhytA__2wvQ","width":1944},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115623591626747192241/photos\">a beauregard</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAA2lGLeytP1Eo0nIe_a-ml4eW9xdMXbiTo8BQij_tL2IBtd9Qd1pJDEhPEF-4ypXhraLSgTLa9Bv8D6pOelpvRoEw3GoO5_G1ZPyV5cDqqRXYEaZL7AGN77otQ0Qo50rb9EhBK4oPCeFf4BKD5_lyjfqKmGhR59yKmhuLhv-qTKzyD0jlau1YwHQ","width":4032},{"height":5312,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110848241892026538641/photos\">Dennis Shanoff</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAdlDGdD00jBf5hOZ49bpJUfjPzH0m0G5sIXOkP5KEqbksfqL33k-9uxUyW3LqhJjat4Jbggq6C_8bmfsclSFjdhJz2NayfOsE-nyyMNEN-GwPtZfhpc50HT9Nkn5jKNWxEhCCkJ6WpbssuAGn-JdibF_LGhSPJDtJGvkFcwb6HRhoVxWBrR4EbQ","width":2988},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115623591626747192241/photos\">a beauregard</a>"],"photo_reference":"CmRaAAAAL5u0ksBwwzBYwycDHNqTEtKqdaGpPRB9REBvNVl_6E4HgiuEOkYpZphocizNd-EozrlE05Zwz1wC2ZcibsqF0CI3-wP8yJyFC76Lu-yZkHrNyAUxs85GGg8xOLTUAzlXEhBQne5bG7eQQn8pW8DszBqVGhQqkbf-vt6WC8QRdGzuGeUpoYQaww","width":4032}],"place_id":"ChIJbQa_U41q4okRJsbAM3zX_WM","rating":3.4,"reference":"CmRRAAAAPU4b-A3ebudL3C27zOGt3pH0uqRXiRmY_feRH3O4SXJpIB7ghnQRsOwDRe0nUssISkr3V_pdwv6BXxHeMvneYGUWLFOTRe_aUlnDQKGpkrXj3bOoFBx7QGdo5ZWgJbKpEhDIJX5_r27SlpSsb9hLIpHZGhSC_JiK3IVPnom3nuQLNOOXZUFsaw","reviews":[{"author_name":"Papa Joe Gaudet","author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/111381118825182249763/reviews","language":"en","profile_photo_url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lJEMylIg98M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAATvY/njN-66RVAp0/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5/photo.jpg","rating":5,"relative_time_description":"2 weeks ago","text":"I dropped in on a cold quiet Tuesday evening. The food was outstanding as was the service. I wish I had more time to enjoy the atmosphere. Next time (and there will be a next time), I'll bring a date. She'll very likely appreciate my good taste. BTW, they are hiring right now and the staff looks happy.","time":1515541362},{"author_name":"Christine D'","author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/110635532521172813159/reviews","language":"en","profile_photo_url":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-neX3OzkbUe4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AA6ZPT6K8ZOkQiewnkB6bxg3VaKuVFIa5Q/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg","rating":5,"relative_time_description":"a week ago","text":"Late lunch on a Friday afternoon. We had sandwiches (a burger and chicken sand.) which were both quite good. Flat bread with goat cheese bruschetta app was delicious! Waiter/bartender was knowledgeable and SO personable. Even if we had struck out with our food selections he would be reason enough to go back. He engaged with every patron in the place. The only thing I'm sorry about is that I didn't get his name. The Crazy Goat is lucky to have him.","time":1515820810},{"author_name":"Lee Goodwin","author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117058651202426601746/reviews","language":"en","profile_photo_url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XcqH9W_RTeY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEI/Y75Cnl2eE_k/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg","rating":5,"relative_time_description":"a month ago","text":"The food is delicious. I had a special of stuffed roasted acorn squash, unreal. The atmosphere and server John were excellent. Can't wait to come here again!","time":1512852799},{"author_name":"happy2say1hello","author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109024209580809571111/reviews","language":"en","profile_photo_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Oct8pO1R3w4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AA6ZPT4gyixHn6uuGcL_-2l1PmC9ztLTUg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg","rating":1,"relative_time_description":"a month ago","text":"I worked here and the owners treated the staff like garbage. Worst job experience I've ever had. Not to mention the food wasn't that great but so expensive. Please save your money for a restaurant that treats its staff better.","time":1512504706},{"author_name":"Tracy Long","author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/102667733449818335247/reviews","language":"en","profile_photo_url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-uc5qHDhCNjs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AA6ZPT6KjwgNKU-cDRvtgpFDyG809i0BlA/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg","rating":3,"relative_time_description":"in the last week","text":"Server was very personable and friendly. Food was ok. Very limited menu.  Liked the ambiance.","time":1516936344}],"scope":"GOOGLE","types":["restaurant","food","point_of_interest","establishment"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=7205151907306849830","utc_offset":-300,"vicinity":"76 North Main Street, Concord","website":"http://www.crazygoatconcord.com/"},"status":"OK"}
```

Comment: try `$rev = json_decode($data,true)` then you can `$rev['result']`

Comment: I got back "Array"

Comment: do $rev['result']['reviews']

Comment: Still just getting "Array", I tried $rev["result"]["review"][0] and got got me nothing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rev = json_decode($data,true);
$reviews = $rev["result"]["reviews"];
foreach($reviews as $review){
    $author_name = $review["author_name"];
    echo $author_name."<br>";
}
```

Comment: breaking the site

Comment: I missed a colon at the end of `$rev = json_decode($data,true)` . The code is working for me.

Comment: It's not outputting anything, I wonder if it is because I am calling the function inside an html element <?php echo do_api_call() ?>

Comment: you can't do `echo do_api_call() ` if do_api_call() has return "my test" then echo do_api_call() will print my test

Comment: I updated my code. do your echos inside the for loop

Comment: I am calling this in a totally different file, I am not getting output with <?php echo $author_name ?>

Comment: explain your file structure in your post. give more details.

Comment: sorry, that did work echoing it in the function and then calling the function in my html element  <?php echo do_api_call() ?>.

Comment: i have to put each of these in a different html element what would you recommend? As in, review 1 in element 1 and review 2 in element 2 etc